# SslStream<TcpStream> read does not return client's message

Tags: ssl, tcp, rust, openssl, sslstream

I am trying to implement a client-server application using TLS (openssl). I followed the example given in rust doc for my code's structure: [example](https://docs.rs/openssl/0.10.30/openssl/ssl/index.html)
**Server Code**

```
fn handle_client(mut stream: SslStream<TcpStream>){
    println!("Passed in handling method");
    let mut data = vec![];
    let length = stream.read(&mut data).unwrap();
    println!("read successfully; size read:{}", length);

    stream.write(b"From server").unwrap();
    stream.flush().unwrap();

    println!("{}", String::from_utf8_lossy(&data));
}


fn main() {
    //remember: certificate should always be signed

    let mut acceptor = SslAcceptor::mozilla_intermediate(SslMethod::tls()).unwrap();
    acceptor.set_private_key_file("src/keyfile/key.pem", SslFiletype::PEM).unwrap();
    acceptor.set_certificate_file("src/keyfile/certs.pem",SslFiletype::PEM).unwrap();
    acceptor.check_private_key().unwrap();
    let acceptor = Arc::new(acceptor.build());

    let listener = TcpListener::bind("127.0.0.1:9000").unwrap();

    for stream in listener.incoming(){
        match stream{
            Ok(stream)=>{
                println!("a receiver is connected");
                let acceptor = acceptor.clone();
                //thread::spawn(move || {
                    let stream = acceptor.accept(stream).unwrap();
                    handle_client(stream);
                //});
            }
            Err(_e)=>{println!{"connection failed"}}
        }
    }


    println!("Server");
}
```

**Client Code**

```
fn main() {
    let mut connector = SslConnector::builder(SslMethod::tls()).unwrap();
    connector.set_verify(SslVerifyMode::NONE); //Deactivated verification due to authentication error
    connector.set_ca_file("src/keyfile/certs.pem");
    let connector = connector.build();

    let stream = TcpStream::connect("127.0.0.1:9000").unwrap();
    let mut stream = connector.connect("127.0.0.1",stream).unwrap();

    stream.write(b"From Client").unwrap();
    stream.flush().unwrap();
    println!("client sent its message");

    let mut res = vec![];
    stream.read_to_end(&mut res).unwrap();
    println!("{}", String::from_utf8_lossy(&res));
   // stream.write_all(b"client").unwrap();

    println!("Client");
}
```

The Server code and the client code both compile without issues, albeit with some warnings. The client is able to connect to the server. But when the client writes its message *From Client* to the stream, the **stream.read** called in  *handle_client()* returns nothing. Furthermore, when the server writes its message *From Server*, the client is able to receive that.
**Hence, is there an issue with the way I use SslStream or on the way I configured my server**?

Comment: You have `read` in the server, but `read_to_end` in the client. `read` may return immediately if the data hasn't been received yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I presume when you say `stream.read` returns nothing, that it returns a zero value indicating that nothing was read.

The [`Read`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.Read.html) trait API says this:

> This function does not provide any guarantees about whether it blocks
> waiting for data, but if an object needs to block for a read and
> cannot, it will typically signal this via an Err return value.
>
> If n is 0, then it can indicate one of two scenarios:
>
> - This reader has reached its "end of file" and will likely no longer be
>   able to produce bytes. Note that this does not mean that the reader
>   will always no longer be able to produce bytes.
> - The buffer specified was 0 bytes in length.
>
> It is not an error if the returned value n is smaller than the buffer
> size, even when the reader is not at the end of the stream yet. This
> may happen for example because fewer bytes are actually available
> right now (e. g. being close to end-of-file) or because read() was
> interrupted by a signal.

So, you need to repeatedly call `read` until you receive all the bytes you expect, or you get an error.

If you know exactly how much you want to read (as you do in this case) you can call `read_exact` which will read exactly the number of bytes needed to fill the supplied buffer.

If you want to read up until a delimeter (such as a newline or other character) you can use a [`BufReader`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/struct.BufReader.html), which provides methods such as [`read_until`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.BufRead.html#method.read_until) or [`read_line`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.BufRead.html#method.read_line).